# Independently greyed out shortcut text in context menu using WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I would like to do the following:

[image]

The shortcut text is greyed as if the menu item were disabled whilst the item itself is not disabled, using the standard WinForms API I can not see how I would achieve this!

Is there a way to separately 'disable' the shortcut text item only?

Comment: Nope. It is not possible out of the box. You must paint this on your self with the `OnPaint` event.

Comment: I figured as much, should I edit my question to ask about to do that?

Comment: I think you mean you want the main text to be back and the shortcut text next to it to be grey.

So I'm guessing you want Copy to be coloured black and Ctrl+C to be coloured grey?
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I wouldn't go away from the windows default behavior. Because every user thinkgs, that this command is disabled.

Comment: Not really, it's pretty standard. An example is in the Chrome right click menu, I have the items that are enabled coloured in black, the ones that aren't in grey and no matter if they are enabled or not, the shortcuts are in grey.

Comment: The screenshot is from Chrome :)

Comment: Would be interesting to know why somebody -1'd this?

Comment: It is not "standard". It is done in Chrome—a single application, a consistent interface rule-breaker. This is the very definition of non-standard. And it's quite confusing in Chrome. You'll notice that Windows itself does *not* do this. Neither should you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no build-in property to disable the short-cuts only. However, you can achieve this using OnPaint event in which you can set color as you want.